# Slicing a certain portion of an array to a new array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays in Matlab.

```
X = dim(700, 1000) 

Y = dim(1, 1000)
```

The values in Y varies between 0 to 9. I want to find the indices of Y whose value is a certain value i, and copy the corresponding values in X.

For example,

```
[a,b] = find(Y == 5)
```

Let's say there are 20 cells whose value was 5 in Y. Then a and b would look like, `a = [1,1,1,1,1, .... 1]` (because there is only one column), and `b = [2, 3, 10, 15 .... ]`

Now I want to take `X(:, b's value)`. What's the efficient way of writing this code in MATLAB? One naive way I can think of is:

```
  for i in size(b)
      X' = [X', X(:, b)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to take certain columns of `X` that are delineated by those corresponding locations in `Y` and construct a new matrix that samples from those locations in `Y`.  All you have to do is:

```
ind = 5; %// Value you are searching for
Xout = X(:,Y == ind);
```

`Y == ind` is a logical vector where `0` doesn't satisfy the condition you are searching for, and `1` satisfies the condition you are looking for.  For example, if `Y` is:

```
Y = [5 5 4 4 3 5 2 1]
```

`Y == 5` would give:

```
[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

You can use logical indexing to slice into an array or matrix and extract out what you want.  Therefore, if you did:

```
X(:, Y == 5);
```

This means that we wish to extract out all of the rows at columns 1, 2 and 6.  Therefore, you would extract out a three column matrix that samples from columns 1, 2 and 6 from `X`.

Therefore, if I understand your problem correctly, you wish to extract out columns from `X` where the corresponding locations in `Y` need to match certain criteria.  The most efficient way to do that is what I outlined at the beginning of this post.

---

Hope this helps!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you need is to get the sorted indices for `Y` and use those indices to index into `X` to get the expected output. Here's the code -

```
[~,idx] = sort(Y)
X_out = X(:,idx)
```

---

**Sample run for explanation**

I. Random inputs, X and Y -

```
X =
    0.2967    0.2625    0.4886    0.5468    0.6791    0.8852    0.3354
    0.3188    0.8010    0.5785    0.5211    0.3955    0.9133    0.6797
    0.4242    0.0292    0.2373    0.2316    0.3674    0.7962    0.1366
    0.5079    0.9289    0.4588    0.4889    0.9880    0.0987    0.7212
    0.0855    0.7303    0.9631    0.6241    0.0377    0.2619    0.1068
Y =
     1     4     2     3     4     5     2
```

II. The sorted indices for `Y` would be -

```
idx =
     1     3     7     4     2     5     6
```

These column indices (idx) would be used to extract specific columns from X.

- Since `Y==1` is for the first index in `Y`, the first column of output would be `X(:,1)`.
- Since `Y==2` is for the third & seventh indices in `Y`, the third and seventh columns from X, that is `X(:,3)` & `X(:,7)` would be appended
  to the output array.

This appending process would continue until we are done with all indices in `Y` and thus giving us the final output as listed next -

```
out =
    0.2967    0.4886    0.3354    0.5468    0.2625    0.6791    0.8852
    0.3188    0.5785    0.6797    0.5211    0.8010    0.3955    0.9133
    0.4242    0.2373    0.1366    0.2316    0.0292    0.3674    0.7962
    0.5079    0.4588    0.7212    0.4889    0.9289    0.9880    0.0987
    0.0855    0.9631    0.1068    0.6241    0.7303    0.0377    0.2619
```